# push notification using firebase issue(ios, swift 4)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

Did not get the push notification data while sending notifcation through my php  server using fire base registration token and server key.But it works when i send notification from firebase.Anybody please help me

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: check with your php code.

Comment: Please check the object of your notification payload. Also, check if notification is being delivered when the app is active or not. If the object is not proper, notification will be delivered only when the app is active and if the payload is proper it will be there in notification drawer.

Comment: possible Sender ID issue, please check that once.

Comment: post the response of your php call to firebase as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that to receive push notification in iOS the payload format should be like this

```
 {
 "to" : "your token here",
 "notification" : {
 "body" : "great match!",
 "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark"
 },
 "data" : {
 "body" : "great match!",
 "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark"
 } 
}
```